# Filling fields with subscription values with Apollo-Angular with codegen

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, prisma-graphql, apollo-angular

Hello) I want the category fields to be filled in the form with values from the category that I received from the server.

I'm doing similarly from a course that uses RestAPI, but I'm using Nestjs - Apollo - Angular and I can't seem to achieve this with this stack.

This is implemented with the .subscribe method but it's not in apollo-angular

**Here's how it's done in the course.**

1. The teacher gets the category from the server and uses its name to set as the value of the field that is in the given control.

```
private _checkEditMode() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if(params['id']) {
        this.editmode = true;
        this._getOneCategory(params['id']).subscribe(category => {
        this.f['name'].setValue(category.name)
        this.f['icon'].setValue(category.icon)
        })
      }  
    });
  }


private _getOneCategory(categoryId: string) {
    
    const catId = {
      input: {
        id:categoryId
      }
    }
    this.$category = this.getOneCategoryGQL
    .watch(catId)
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(map(result => result.data))
  }
```

*How does this work on Apollo-Angular?*

2. Teacher Clicks on the "edit category" button...
   [image: Edit category by id]
3. Values from the category.id are pulled from the server into the fields.
   [image: get data for edit]

**2 blocks of questions:**

1. If I use codegen types (Apollo-angular), what do I need to do to implement this? Do I need to create subscriptions separately, or is there some method to make this easier?

It’s still difficult for me to study the apollo-angular documentation, could you describe in detail how to implement getting data from the server to edit it inside the fields.

2. What basic principles am I not understanding when asking this question? What would you recommend to study? What questions would you like me to ask?